# Powershell command to fetch all file path for all desired files extensions

Tags: windows, powershell, directory, subdirectory

I want to search all drives using PowerShell on windows machine to get the list of all files along with their extensions -

1. Based on desired extension we pass in it like - `*.mp3` or
2. Fetch all files with multiple extensions like - `*.txt, *.mp3` etc.

I tried below script but its giving only information from where we are running it. But I want to scan whole machine.

```
Get-ChildItem -Path .\ -Filter ***.doc** -Recurse -File| Sort-Object Length -Descending | ForEach-Object { $_.BaseName }
```

Comment: look up how to get the local drive letters. once you have that, you can iterate thru the resulting list. [*grin*] something like this `powershell list drive letters` will get you started.

Comment: Welcome as a new user to SO. Please take the [tour] and also read [ASK]. What is an output of `BaseName` sorted by file length worth, when  not knowing the location of the file?

Comment: If you are going to go through the trouble of listing all the files I suggest getting the filehash as well so you can determine if you have duplicate files. A simple file name search will not detect if the same file has been saved with different name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more than what the original question asked, but if you are going to go through the trouble of listing all your files, I suggest getting the filehash as well so you can determine if you have duplicates. A simple file name search will not detect if the same file has been saved with a different name. Adding to what @lit (https://stackoverflow.com/users/447901/lit) has posted:

```
$ExtensionList = @('.txt', '.doc', '.docx', '.mp3')
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem |
    ForEach-Object  {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $_.Root -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
            Where-Object { $ExtensionList -eq $_.Extension } |
            ## ForEach-Object { $_.Name, $_.FullName, $_.GetHashCode() }
            Select-Object @{Name="Name";Expression={$_.Name}}, @{Name="Hash";Expression={$_.GetHashCode()}}, @{Name="FullName";Expression={$_.FullName}} | 
            Export-Csv -Path C:\Temp\testing.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
    }
```

The addition of the file hash will allow you to see if you have duplicates and the full name will allow you to see where they are located.

Comment: Thanks, your script is showing much more relevant info but can you please help me with putting info like - filename | file path | file hash and that also into a text file output so that it can be easily manipulated in excel

Comment: I edited my code above which will create a CSV in C:\Temp, so you can open it in Excel. Both of the answers above answered your original question though, so make sure you mark one of them with the green check!

Comment: Thanks its working perfectly fine but in new script I guess you have removed the functionality to put desired extensions, If I want to change & add extension where I can put them.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the top line in my copy/paste, the answer has been edited above. I am still not seeing the green check mark for either of the answers above though, and I only added to @lit answer.

Comment: I ran your script by removing .txt but even after removing I am still getting results for .txt files, why is it so ?
$ExtensionList = @('.doc', '.docx', '.mp3')

and what if I add more desired extensions in that list ?

Comment: Looks like there is an issue using -Contains in arrays, swap that operator for -eq and it appears to behave better.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout the `Get-PSDrive` cmdlet. It returns a list of drives, and you can specify just disk drives with the `-PSProvider FileSystem` parameter:

```
foreach ( $drive in $(Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem) ) {
Get-ChildItem -Path $drive.Root -Filter ***.doc** -Recurse -File |
Sort-Object Length -Descending | 
ForEach-Object { $_.BaseName }
}
```

Didn't test that but you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Using `-Include` on `Get-ChildItem` will allow you to specify a list of extensions. The `-ErrorAction` will cause it to skip drives that are not available such as an unmounted CD drive.

```
Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem |
    ForEach-Object  {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $_.Root -Recurse -Include '*.doc*', '*.txt' -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
            ForEach-Object { $_.Name }
    } |
        ForEach-Object {[PSCustomObject]@{HashCode = $_.GetHashCode(); FullName = $_.FullName}}
} |
Export-Csv -Path $TempFile -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII
```

**Update:**

Here is a better way. It will prevent unknown extensions from getting into the mix such as "Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Publish.Docker.targets."

```
$ExtensionList = @('.txt', '.doc', '.docx', '.mp3')
$TempFile = Join-Path -path $Env:TEMP -ChildPath "$($pid.ToString()).tmp"

Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem |
    ForEach-Object  {
        Get-ChildItem -Path $_.Root -Recurse -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
            Where-Object { $ExtensionList -contains $_.Extension } |
        ForEach-Object {
            [PSCustomObject]@{
                HashCode = $_.GetHashCode();
                DirectoryName = $_.DirectoryName
                Name = $_.Name
            }
        }
    } |
    Export-Csv -Path $TempFile -Delimiter ';' -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII
Write-Host "The temp file is $TempFile"
```

Comment: Its perfectly working fine but along with file & their extension, I also want to get their full path where they are can we add some "|" or ";" in between file name & their path so that it can also be divided into excel for better visibility and put output in a single txt file.

Comment: @Vijaykhurava - The answer has been edited to emit the directory name and the file name separately. Use `Join-Path` to put these back together. Use the `-Delimiter` parameter on `Export-Csv` to specify the desired field separator.

Comment: Thanks but really sorry I am not good with powershell :-) when I am running your script as it is, its not generating any output under temp or export-csv searched whole computer, but when I am removing $temp file & last line of export-csv its generating the output but output not divided by ; or | sign.

Comment: @Vijaykhurava - I mentioned using the `-Delimiter` parameter earlier. The name of the temp file is written to the console at the end. You can get good with PowerShell.

Comment: Thank you so much @lit, I tried to mark resolved for both but I guess only one is allowed but really appreciate the prompt & supportive way you helped me here :-)